# Downscale array for decimal factor

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11

Is there efficient way to downscale number of elements in array by decimal factor?

I want to downsize elements from one array by certain factor.

Example: 
If I have 10 elements and need to scale down by factor 2.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
scaled to
1.5 3.5 5.5 7.5 9.5
```

Grouping 2 by 2 and use arithmetic mean.

My problem is what if I need to downsize array with 10 elements to 6 elements? In theory I should group 1.6 elements and find their arithmetic mean, but how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "In theory I should group 1.6 elements"? A count of elements is always a natural number.
Do you always scale by 2?

Comment: @Superlokkus I think OP meant "group by 1.66666666(6), i.e. by 10.0/6.0.

Comment: When you say you want to "downsize an array of 10 to 6", how are you treating the second element?  That is, if you take element 0 and 60% of element 1, are you going to take the whole element 1 in the next iteration, skip it (dropping the remaining portion), or just take the other 40% (which will require taking element 2 and then 20% of element 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before suggesting a solution, let's define "downsize" in a more formal way. I would suggest this definition:

> Downsizing starts with an array `a[N]` and produces an array `b[M]` such that the following is true:
>
> 1. `M <= N` - otherwise it would be upsizing, not downsizing
> 2. `SUM(b) = (M/N) * SUM(a)` - The sum is reduced proportionally to the number of elements
> 3. Elements of `a` participate in computation of `b` in the order of their occurrence in `a`

Let's consider your example of downsizing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` to six elements. The total for your array is 55, so the total for the new array would be `(6/10)*55 = 33`. We can achieve this total in two steps:

- Walk the array `a` totaling its elements until we've reached the integer part of `N/M` fraction (it must be an improper fraction by rule 1 above)
- Let's say that `a[i]` was the last element of `a` that we could take as a whole in the current iteration. Take the fraction of `a[i+1]` equal to the fractional part of `N/M`
- Continue to the next number starting with the remaining fraction of `a[i+1]`
- Once you are done, your array `b` would contain `M` numbers totaling to `SUM(a)`. Walk the array once more, and scale the result by `N/M`.

Here is how it works with your example:

```
b[0] = a[0] + (2/3)*a[1]              = 2.33333
b[1] = (1/3)*a[1] + a[2] + (1/3)*a[3] = 5
b[2] = (2/3)*a[3] + a[4]              = 7.66666
b[3] = a[5] + (2/3)*a[6]              = 10.6666
b[4] = (1/3)*a[6] + a[7] + (1/3)*a[8] = 13.3333
b[5] = (2/3)*a[8] + a[9]              = 16
                                        --------
                                Total = 55
```

Scaling down by `6/10` produces the final result:

```
1.4 3 4.6 6.4 8 9.6 (Total = 33)
```

Here is a simple implementation in C++:

```
double need = ((double)a.size()) / b.size();
double have = 0;
size_t pos = 0;
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != a.size() ; i++) {
    if (need >= have+1) {
        b[pos] += a[i];
        have++;
    } else {
        double frac = (need-have); // frac is less than 1 because of the "if" condition
        b[pos++] += frac * a[i];   // frac of a[i] goes to current element of b
        have = 1 - frac;
        b[pos] += have * a[i];     // (1-frac) of a[i] goes to the next position of b
    }
}
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != b.size() ; i++) {
    b[i] /= need;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qDsdaw)

Comment: I am not sure how will sum claim behave in case of negative elements. I am working with signed int16_t numbers. Other two claims are correct..

Comment: @Steva `sum` on negatives should work in the same way that it works with averaging from your example. Imagine scaling `1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5` down to 5 elements. Averaging would yield `0, 0, 0, 0, 0`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 6/10 is not 2/3.  That is, 6/10 is .6, not .6666....  The basic formula you (M/N) is correct, but the simplified version using his example is not.  It should be `a[0] + .6 * a[1]`.

Comment: @ZacHowland 2/3 comes from (10/6)-1, i.e. (5/3)-1. By "scaling down" I mean "dividing by", so the result is a division by 10/6, or multiplication by 0.6. I ran the numbers through Excel again to make sure that the results match the expected values (i.e. sum of 55*0.6, which is 33) and my numbers did match.

Comment: Okay, this should do. I am gonna try to implement it and see how behaves, but I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work :) Thank you! :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Perhaps I'm missing something, but the OP states he wants to reduce an array of 10 elements to an array of 6.  I don't see anywhere in the problem where he states he wants to reduce the total by 40% (e.g. making it 60% of the original).

Comment: @ZacHowland I made this suggestion based on the observation that OP's solution reduces the total by 50% through averaging when reducing the array from 10 to 5 elements. Since the question is not clear on the amount of reduction, I stated my assumption explicitly as part of explaining the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to resort to some form of interpolation, as the number of elements to average isn't integer.

You can consider computing the prefix sum of the array, i.e.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

yields by summation

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

Then perform linear interpolation to get the intermediate values that you are lacking, like at `0*, 10/6, 20/6, 30/5*, 40/6, 50/6, 60/6*`. (Those with an asterisk are readily available).

```
0  1 10/6 2  3 20/6  4  5  6  40/6  7  8  50/6  9
1  3 15/3 6 10 35/3 15 21 28 100/3 36 45 145/3 55
```

Now you get fractional sums by subtracting values in pairs. The first average is

```
(15/3-1)/(10/6) = 12/5
```

Comment: I thought about interpolation, but I have aprox  >9 mil elements in array, computing polynomial interpolation would be pretty slow if not unusable.

Comment: @steva: I didn't advise polynomial interpolation. Polynomial interpolation doesn't work for more than 10 points. But there are excellent piecewise polynomial schemes, that are fast. (My example used simple piecewise linear interpolation.) My main point was that interpolation needs to be performed on the prefix sum, not on the original sequence.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of anything in the C++ library that will crank out something like this, all fully cooked and ready to go.

So you'll have to, pretty much, roll up your sleeves and go to work. At this point, the question of what's the "efficient" way of doing it boils down to its very basics. Which means:

1) Calculate how big the output array should be. Based on the description of the issue, you should be able to make that calculation even before looking at the values in the input array. You know the input array's `size()`, you can calculate the `size()` of the destination array.

2) So, you `resize()` the destination array up front. Now, you no longer need to worry about the time wasted in growing the size of the dynamic output array, incrementally, as you go through the input array, making your calculations.

3) So what's left is the actual work: iterating over the input array, and calculating the downsized values.

```
auto b=input_array.begin();
auto e=input_array.end();

auto p=output_array.begin();
```

Don't see many other options here, besides brute force iteration and calculations. Iterate from `b` to `e`, getting your samples, calculating each downsized value, and saving the resulting value into `*p++`.